# Get 'ScrollView' from ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

How get a 'ScrollView' from ListView ?

I want implement that function

```
public void onScrollChanged(ScrollView who, int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
  final int headerHeight = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_mensagem_list_header)
          .getHeight() - getActivity().getActionBar().getHeight();
  final float ratio = (float) Math.min(Math.max(t, 0), headerHeight) / headerHeight;
  final int newAlpha = (int) (ratio * 255);
  mActionBarBackgroundDrawable.setAlpha(newAlpha);
}

((NotifyingScrollView) LISTVIEWHERE    ).setOnScrollChangedListener(mOnScrollChangedListener);
```

Comment: Instead of using ListView Scrolling, try to do this in ListView's getView(). It is enough powerful to handle all changes occur on list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a OnScrollListener for a listview and get the callbacks of scroll states like below.

```
yourListViewReference.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final int headerHeight = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fragment_mensagem_list_header)
      .getHeight() - getActivity().getActionBar().getHeight();
    final float ratio = (float) Math.min(Math.max(t, 0), headerHeight) / headerHeight;
    final int newAlpha = (int) (ratio * 255);
    mActionBarBackgroundDrawable.setAlpha(newAlpha);
}
 });
 }
```

Comment: I need a few paramters like 
Parameters

l  Current horizontal scroll origin.
t  Current vertical scroll origin.
oldl  Previous horizontal scroll origin.
oldt  Previous vertical scroll origin.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Be more Clear with the Question on what you are trying to achieve !**

- Why are you adding `ScrollView` to a `Listview` ?
- Adding `ScrollView` to a listview is a bad practice in android
  because `listView` already is provided with the scroll functionality
- If you add a `scrollView` to a `listView` android will get confused
  on which Touch to detect, `ListView` or `ScrollView`
- If you are adding `ScrollView` to `ListView` Please re-Think on your
  design beccause it is not a good practice

---

### Quoting from the docs

**You should never use a `ScrollView` with a `ListView`**, because `ListView` takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in `ListView` for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the `ListView` to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by `ScrollView`.

You can add your views as header and footer to your listview. The header and footer will  scroll.

---

***You can also Hack your way to solve this, Check This Solution from [tacone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/358813/tacone), But i would not recommend this since its a bad practice, and may lead to performance issues***

---

**ExpandableHeightGridView.java:**

```
    package com.example;
    public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView
    {

        boolean expanded = false;

        public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context)
        {
            super(context);
        }

        public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
        {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                int defStyle)
        {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        public boolean isExpanded()
        {
            return expanded;
        }

        @Override
        public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
        {
            // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
            if (isExpanded())
            {
                // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
                // View.MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
                int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK,
                        MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
                params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            else
            {
                super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            }
        }

        public void setExpanded(boolean expanded)
        {
            this.expanded = expanded;
        }
    }
```

**Include it in your layout like this:**

```
    <com.example.ExpandableHeightGridView
        android:id="@+id/myId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="20dp" />
```

**Lastly you just need to ask it to expand:**

```
    mAppsGrid = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.myId);
    mAppsGrid.setExpanded(true);
```

---

**Let me know if you need any help!**

Answer (score 0):

Use the OnScrollListener for ListView and GridView, you can get the 't' by the below formula

```
        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            View c = view.getChildAt(0);
            if (c != null) {
                int t = -c.getTop() + view.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight();
                final int headerHeight = mHeaderImage.getHeight() - getActionBar().getHeight();
                final float ratio = (float) Math.min(Math.max(t, 0), headerHeight) / headerHeight;
                final int newAlpha = (int) (ratio * 255);
                ((MainActivity) mActivity).getDrawableBGActionBar().setAlpha(newAlpha);

            }

        }
```